# Compiling within the code with g++ in Code::Blocks

Tags: windows, c++11, g++

I am trying to write a game similar to code hunt (https://www.codehunt.com/about.aspx)
So How this will work, is the player can modify a .cpp file, which will be compiled  and and ran within the code, but I have problems about how to compile it.
I'am using the latest g++ compiler, and this is how I try to achive this:

```
void Builder::build(const char* file){
 std::string s = "g++ ";
 s += file;
 s += " -o test.o";
 system(s.c_str());
}
```

Where we get the .cpp file's name, and this code piece is supposed to build test.o
This is just a test now, it might get more complex, I just wanted to test if the compiler will work within the code, but I get this error message when I try to run this:

```
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.9.3/../../../libmingw32.a(main.o):(.text.startup+0xa7):undefined reference to 'WinMain@16'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

PATH for mingw is set correctly, I checked.
I am using Windows 8.1, g++ 4.9.3 and Code::Blocks.

Comment: Are you sure you want to name the output file with a `.o` suffix, like an *object* file and not an executable?

Comment: Also, just running some user-given code is a big security hole, big enough to fly a Saturn V rocket though it.

Answer (score 1):

In Windows execution doesn't normally start at the `main` functions, it starts at the `WinMain` function, which takes some Windows-specific arguments. You should read e.g. [this `WinMain` reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633559(v=vs.85).aspx) for more information.

That some programs still seems to start at a `main` function is because there is an object file linked with the program that contains the `WinMain` function which calls your `main` function.

Answer (score 0):

OK I'm an idiot, so the problem was that I was trying to build a file whitout a main function. This was deliberat design choice at first, but...well yeah. Sorry about that.
Thank you Joachim Pileborg for leading me to it.